# How to send notification from websites to facebook?

Tags: facebook, notifications, web

I have been trying to send notification from website to a specific list of users but the problem is I dont know if there is anyway but I did went through related contents and realized it is possible through facebook apps.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

> App-to-User Notifications are available to all Facebook Web Games. The
>   notifications are only surfaced on the desktop web version of
>   Facebook. Apps can send notifications to people who have authorised
>   the app. No special or extended permission is required.

Comment: yes i do know that but was wondering if I missed something and if there is any other way.Anyway sir thanks

Comment: no, you did not miss anything, what other way would you expect?

Comment: Don't know was just curious :)